Send Intent to Start Activity With Multiple String Extras Via ADB
I am trying to start an activity via Intent with multiple String extras via ADB command. I have the same problem as this. The only difference is that, I need to send MULTIPLE String extras.
This is how I send a single String extra:
adb shell am start -a "com.company.MY_COMMAND" --es "extra1" "Hello" -t "text/plain"

How do I do send multiple String extras?

For multiple String extras:
adb shell am start -a "com.company.MY_COMMAND" --es "extra1" "Hello" -e "extra2" "World" -t "text/plain"

To extract these on the receiving end:
String hello = intent.getStringExtra("extra1");
String world = intent.getStringExtra("extra2");


String s1 = intent.getStringExtra("extra1");
String s2 = intent.getStringExtra("extra2");
